# Function with input vs Function without input - Python

Tags: python, function

This may seem like a basic question but it has me confused.  The following 2 examples work in a similar way I believe (assuming input is the same) It prompts the user for a number, multiplies that number by 5 and returns the answer.

My question is, why and when would you ever choose the second example over the first? (and vice versa).  In more general terms, why have functions with arguments as opposed to having the arguments given within the function.  If that makes sense.  If this is a bad example I apologize, I am just trying to wrap my head around this.

Thanks

No arguments:

```
def func():
    x = int(input('Enter a number:'))
    y = x * 5
    print(y)

func()
```

One argument:

```
def func_2(y):
    x = int(input('Enter a number:'))
    y = x * 5
    return y

print(func_2(6))
```

Comment: The second version doesn't make any sense, you have an argument `y`, but it wasn't even used in the function.

Comment: In the second example `y` is worth nothing. After all you'll calculate `y` in `y=x*5`. So, the first example is more accurate.

Comment: The only other notable difference is the print statement's inside the function for the former, and `print` prints the return value of the function for the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question!

Basically, the difference between the two functions are that the first function handles the calculation and the presentation to the user. The second function only handles the calculation. (correction, the second function also handles accepting the user input, I would change that... like so:)

```
def func_2(x):
    y = x * 5
return y

x = int(input('Enter a number:'))
print(func_2(x))
```

## Reasons for using the second function:

## First Reason: Reusability

Let's say that you need to get a value from your function multiple times and you don't always want to print the result. Perhaps sometimes the result will be printed to the user, but in another instance the result will be output to a file. Separating the calculation and presentation may save you time later on.

## Second Reason: Recursion

You may want to recursively call your function. Keeping your function only about calculation allows you to do things like this - Here is an example of making a function to calculate factorials:

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)
```

(Google "recursion" it is cool)

## Third Reason: Good practice

Kind of my opinion, but I think people will agree. The more we can separate different aspects of code the easier it is to troubleshoot, reuse, and read by others ... and ... probably more ...

Comment: Also, a further though, I would separate out accepting the input from the user too...